# A riddle from the second Psalm (and fourth verse)

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My first riddle. I hope you all enjoy!

> Aeneas was my forerunner, and I influenced Doom;
>
> Many a man have I condemned, I’m both elegant and crude;
>
> I delve through burning wickedness, to the dark and frozen liar;
>
> And I climb the mount of suffering, to reach Jehovah’s fire.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are probably

> Dante Alighieri, author of the poem commonly known as the "Divine Comedy" and more specifically of its first part, the *Inferno*, describing hell.

Aeneas was my forerunner, and I influenced Doom;

> Not quite sure why Aeneas rather than Virgil (author of the *Aeneid*), who is Dante's guide through hell. One portion of *Doom* is actually called *Inferno* and has the protagonist exploring hell.

Many a man have I condemned, I’m both elegant and crude;

> The *Inferno* is full of Dante's political enemies. Dante's poetry is generally considered some of the finest ever written, but many of the punishments he has the inhabitants of hell subjected to are pretty coarse.

I delve through burning wickedness, to the dark and frozen liar;

> The burning wickedness of hell -- at the bottom and centre of which, in the Ninth Circle, is a frozen lake, in the centre of which is Satan himself ("the dark and frozen liar").

And I climb the mount of suffering, to reach Jehovah’s fire.

> After making his way through hell, the second book of the *Comedy* ("Purgatorio") has Dante climbing a mountain on which Purgatory is located, to reach heaven ("Paradiso") for the third book.

Comment: Nice! rot13(V cvpxrq Nrarnf orpnhfr gur punenpgre npghnyyl jrag gb gur Haqrejbeyq orsber nf gur punenpgre Qnagr tbrf gb nyy cynprf va gur Pngubyvp nsgreyvsr.) It could have been conceived either way, however (and I didn’t want to make it too obvious, so I went with mine :) ).

Comment: You didn’t pick up on every hint, but you got most of them; certainly worth a +1 and an accept!

Comment: Ah, should have thought of that about Aeneas. Thanks.